# PHP email linebreak

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

I wrote code to send emails from PHP using HTML and JavaScript (jQuery). In js I defined the following strings:

```
var firstT = "It is " + $("#time").html() + " right now.";
var secondT = "And now, it is " + $("#othTime").html() + ".";

var sendT = firstT + "\r\n" + secondT;
```

Then I send this string to the PHP file:

```
var thTi = "folder/time.php?to=" + $("#perName").val() + "&message=" + sendT;
    $.ajax({
        url: thTi
    });
```

PHP receives this strings and sends it with this code:

```
<?php

    $to = $_GET['to'];
    $subject = "The Subject";
    $message = $_GET['message'];
    $headers = 'From: Me?' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: no-reply@thesite.com' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

So, the problem is - when a person receives the message, it is all in one line. I've added line breaks `\r\n`, even tried with `<br>` and `<br />`. I found somewhere that inserting a dot `.` might solve the problem, but I've tried, and it doesn't.

Comment: I tried with (<br>) and (<br />). (It didnt print out).

Comment: what does your header look like? carriage returns are ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send an html email with `mail()`, you have to add the proper headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Me?' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: no-reply@thesite.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

To clean and add line-breaks to your html:

```
$message = strip_tags($_GET['message'];);
$message_html = preg_replace('/\n/' , '<br />' , $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the double quotes `"` instead of `'` and then `\r\n` will work. So your new code must looks like:

```
$headers = "From: Me?" . "\r\n" .
           "Reply-To: no-reply@thesite.com" . "\r\n" .
           "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an html tages in your mail first thing that you need to do is to set an header type of that mail to html. Append the below lines to the code to the $header variable at the start, before adding the from and other details in this variable.

```
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Me?' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: no-reply@thesite.com' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

for more understanding of this you can see this link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

I hope this helps you.